# How to use fomat function in my user defined function

Tags: postgresql

I have following simple code user defined function that want to format the string.

```
create or replace function func_format_usage(v1 integer, v2 varchar)
returns varchar as $$
declare
res1 varchar;
begin
 -- error
 res1 = execute format('input arguments is %I and %S', v1, v2) ;
 -- also eror
 res1 = format('input arguments is %I and %S', v1, v2);
 return res1;
end
$$ language plpgsql;

select func_format_usage(10,'Ten')
```

whether or not I add the `execute` to call the `format` returns, it complains error complains that there are errors around the format.

But, it is ok to run `select format`

I would ask where the problem is ,thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that this is a syntax exercise. There are two problems:

- Use [execute into](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) instead of the assignment operator. Note that still the example wouldn't work because `execute` expects valid SQL. It will generate a runtime exception.
- The [format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) placeholder `%S` is invalid, should be `%s`.

So here it is. I have replaced `varchar` with `text` which is more common in PostgreSQL.

```sql
create or replace function func_format_usage(v1 integer, v2 text)
returns text language plpgsql as
$$
declare
    res1 text;
begin
 -- execute format('input arguments is %I and %s', v1, v2) into res1;
 res1 := format('input arguments is %I and %s', v1, v2);
 return res1;
end
$$;
```

You can use `execute` like this

```sql
 execute 'select '''||format('input arguments is %I and %s',v1,v2)||'''' into res1;
```

which is by far an overkill and does not make much sense.

Comment: `%I` is the placeholder for an identifier (column or table name) not for integers.

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name, I test and find that %I is used for integer.

Comment: **No it is not.** Granted supplying an integer to `%I` does not create an error nor raise an exception. However it will double quote the value. If subsequently used in SQL/plpgsql it will be interpreted as a Identifier - i.e. the name of a database object. Probably **not what is desired**. With luck you will get an error/exception if not well it does something with that object.  See docs [9.4.1 format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) and [4.1.1. Identifiers and Key Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).